# Why doesn't PyCharm show the output of my code?

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, output

I'm new at using python and PyCharm Environment so I would like to ask something. I'm trying to run the following code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == "_main_":

img = cv2.imread("building_left.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
# Moving average
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.float32) / 25
dst = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel)
# Show images
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title('Original')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title('Averaging')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()`
```

While my code has no errors identified, when I try to run the code all I get is the following line

```
runfile('C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled2/opencv.py', wdir='C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled2')
```

without being able to view the output of my program. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be `if __name__ == '__main__':` (2 underscores before and after main).

Comment: and you have to indent the code after the `if __name...` or paste it correctly.